# C++ - Template + 'using' clause - mismatch argument error

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, typedef, using

I'm trying to use a template and two typedef, but I know that the only way is to insert a 'using' clause like that:

```
template<typename T>
using Car = std::pair<T, T>;
using SparseMatrix = std::vector< Car >;
```

The problem is that gcc gives me the following error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
```

I think the problem is that Car is not a type because of the 'using' clause. How can I resolve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Car` is an alias template, so you need to take a template argument in `SparseMatrix` and forward it on:

```
template <typename T>
using SparseMatrix = std::vector<Car<T>>;
```

Comment: so it's `template<typename T>
using Car = std::pair<T, T>;
template<typename T>
using SparseMatrix = std::vector< Car<T> >;
template<typename T>
class DataHandler{ ... }` the right way to use them?

Comment: But why now, when I declare in another class the object (DataHandler) in which I use the template, I have this error? `error: invalid use of template-name ‘DataHandler’ without an argument list`

Comment: Because `DataHandler` is a template class. You need to use `DataHandler<T>` (although there are some contexts where you can omit the argument).

Comment: But now declaring `DataHandler<T>* dh = NULL;` tells me `error: 'T' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: @rh0x That's because you need a valid template argument. I'd suggest reading up about templates and maybe asking a new question for any issues that come up.